# Creating mapping table in SQL

Tags: sql

Can I create a mapping table out of a #temp table that I have created?

I need to create a mapping table that contains two different tables, but those tables do not have any field in common. However, I created a temp table with case statements and joining the table.

Now, I need to create a mapping table but I'm not sure if I can't create a mapping table out of a temp table.

What should I do?

Comment: We need more information -- how do you have this temp table?  What are the fields in the temp table?  What platform are you using?

Comment: Share what you tried so far, Sample data and your desired output.

Comment: if this is temporary then you can use temp or table variables

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at creating a view instead. That will allow you to include case statements in it and you won't have to update your mapping table every time some data changes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql

If you include more information people will probably help further.